# QT/QML application crashes due to object ownership issue

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qqmlengine

I have a Qt/Qml application which uses a static Qt C++ library. The classes (models etc.) reside in the library whose objects are created in the application's main.cpp or QML files. Some of the classes are derived from QObject. I get segmentation faults when closing screens which have objects of these classes. I need to maintain the objects even after closing screens.

I have tried using QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(). I cannot use it in the constructor of these classes as QQmlEngine class is not available for a library project. So I set it in the application after  the object has been created.

[image: in Qml]

here getDbpointObject() is a slot and returns an object of a class derived from QObject.

Then i pass the object to an internal class's function to set its ownership.

[image]

In some examples saw that its okay to set the ownership after the object has been created. Not sure if its correct or we necessarily need to do it in the constructor, for which i don't have a way?

Comment: "I need to maintain the objects even after closing screens." Why? are you still using the pointObj in the database object regardless of what is done in QML?

Comment: Yes. These db point object are common across screens so I don't create new if It has already been created.

Comment: Please do not include code as a screenshot, use the built-in code formatting feature instead.

Comment: Why are you not able to set the ownership in the constructor? It is a static function, so I do not understand why the library could not set it correctly. Or at least set it in the `getDbpointObject` function.

Comment: It's definitely not required to set the ownership inside the destructor, but I'm not sure whether it is ok to set if after the object is already passed to QML.

Comment: Are you sure these objects are really destructed by QML, or could it be already deleted by some other part of your C++ program?

Comment: Including the relevant parts of the crash stack trace may be useful too.

Comment: I cannot set in constructor or anywhere in the library because the class QQmlEngine is not available in library type of project.

Comment: I did put debug messages which shows that component.ondestructed is followed by the message from class destructor.

Comment: I haven't found the crash stack trace very useful so far. I run the IDE on a VM where debugging directly doesn't work. I have to move the code out of shared directory for debugging. But thats a seperate issue. Anyways for this problem mostly saw Qt function calls all the way down to main.exec and sometimes call where the deleted object is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing any crash anymore. I am not sure if this was the cause but by mistake I had put QString return type from the setownership() call. After correcting it to void, I don't see the crash so seems things are working. Will monitor it further. Thanks for your help.